# Alternative to filter.watch()

Tags: web3js, events, web3-providers

**Here's a scenario:**

1. Dapp backend connects to a remote Ethereum node using external
   HTTP RPC:

---

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/janNFDJkMgDfan"));
```

2. Dapp user sends transaction to a contract and then submits this
   transaction's hash to dapp backend.
3. Dapp backend waits for the pending block to get confirmed and checks
   if the transaction is included in it.

**Here's the problem**:

As it turns out when `web3` object is provided by an external node backend can't use events. For example, backend can't watch for new blocks. The following doesn't work:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter('latest');

filter.watch(function(error, result){
  var block = web3.eth.getBlock(result, true);
  console.log('current block #' + block.number);
});
```

> TypeError: filterCreationErrorCallback is not a function

So, the problem is that backend doesn't know when a new block is mined.

**One way to handle this:**

Backend can query the blockchain every ~20 seconds to check if a new block has been mined.

```
check(){
    web3.eth.getBlock("pending", (error, result) => {
      console.log('error:', error);
      console.log('results', result);
    });
}
setTimeout(check, 20000);
```

and then make sure that the user's transaction was included.

**Another way of handling this is:**

?????

Comment: Does "run your own node" count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've managed to listen to events on the backend. The problem is that the events don't fire consistently.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine/index.js');
const ZeroClientProvider = require('web3-provider-engine/zero.js');

const engine = ZeroClientProvider({
  getAccounts: function(){},
  rpcUrl: 'https://ropsten.infura.io/WEQuhowqe78qdqweqw', //RANDOM ID, TO GET A REAL ONE, REGISTER AT INFURA.IO
})
const web3 = new Web3(engine);

const contractAddress = '0xc740ab099da657612143c34c5f7593a3af5ee6e8';
const contractAbi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"emit","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"myEvent","type":"event"}];
const contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);

const event = contract.myEvent({x: null})
event.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(error, result.args.x.toNumber());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Still haven't got enoguh reputation to comment so I'm just dropping a line as an answer to say you should remove your access code from the example you provided! ;)

> const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/***********"));

Comment: I doubt that this is important as this JS code can be view in the source code of the dapp, so this is probably not a secret.

Comment: You can edit answers/questions with 1 rep.